# Tab control - wait until control become enabled

Tags: c#, tabs

I have multiple controls on one form,and when i select some value from combo box(for example 1) next control became enabled, else next control stay disabled.

Problem is that if i just press 1 and tab, after that next control became enabled, but program  jump over it just like control are still disabled, and tab control selecting next control.

I need to find way how to tab check is control become enabled and go on this control,and if control are still disabled that go on next enabled control.

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a mousetrap for the user, very hard to escape from.  Technically you can handle the keyboard navigation by trapping the Tab key before it can be used to navigate but the user still has an unsolvable problem when he wants to use the mouse to change the focus.  He has nothing decent to click on.

You'll need to re-think your UI design.  One possible solution is to change the ComboBox's DropDownStyle to DropDownList.  Which ought to be pretty appropriate if you use its selected item to enable other controls, there should only be a limited set of valid selections.  If that's not what you want then you need to do something drastic.  Not necessarily limited to hiding controls instead of disabling them.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by the event of the combo-box you using to control your flow.

The "Changed"/"Value changed" events in most languages fire up after the control has lost focus.

Comment: You explain the problem clearly, but.. where is a solution to it? =D

Comment: You can use the "Validating" or "Validated" events, which fire before they lose focus. See this reference on control events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx

PS. My work tasks just arrived, sorry for not providing a more tutorial-ish solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a tag for the UI technology you are using.

If you are using WinForms, then you can try to execute the [SelectNextControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on your control that the user just edited. This will find the 'next' control for you, and activate it.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume it's winforms (playing with disabled/enabled like this in wpf is.. against mvvm rules).

Firstly, ensure what *tab order/index* of your controls is ok. To test, if they are all enabled, then pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> should go through them in the right order. This can be seen easily

[image]

Next thing is to choose one of many possible solutions, to make <kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd> to work:

- disable <kbd>Tab</kbd> key navigation at all;
- make controls to pass control (focus) to specific control (making *tab order* irrelevant);
- use `SelectNextControl` (work best for custom controls, which when will support that tab-flow schema);
- prevent focus changing, do all logic, change focus (theoretically).